# Multiple versions of swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a new to swagger, I built a template according to the documentation, and it was very successful. But I now have 2 versions of API, each version is iterative from the previous version, I want to keep the API of each version, how can I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ApiVersion("1")]  
[ApiVersion("2")]  
[ApiController]  
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]  
public class DummyController : ControllerBase  
{
    [HttpGet]    
    [MapToApiVersion("1")]    
    [Route("Test")]    
    public your_return_type TestV1() { ... }
      
      
    [HttpGet]    
    [MapToApiVersion("2")]    
    [Route("Test")]    
    public your_return_type TestV2() { ... }
}
```

> api/v1/dummy/test
> api/v2/dummy/test

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will try to finish it like this！！

Comment: Kindly leave a feedback if it helps or not :)

Comment: I want to select the version operation on the swagger interface. Sorry, I am not very good at it. Can you give me the complete code?